# execute my setTimeout function after clicking stops

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, settimeout

I have a click event where once you click the div, it is adding and removing classes from two other divs.

Then I have a setTimeout function where it is reversing the classes it added and removed from the two other divs.

The thing is, I need the setTimeout to execute after the clicking stops.

Is there a way to check for the click event to end before the setTimeout can execute?

Everything works but I need it to not do setTimeout until the clicking stops.

Here is my Code:

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
    $(".reg-state").removeClass("active");
    $(".reg-state").addClass("hidden");
    $(".hot-state").removeClass("hidden");  
    $(".hot-state").addClass("active");

    setTImeout(function() {
        $(".reg-state").removeClass("hidden");
        $(".reg-state").addClass("active");
        $(".hot-state").removeClass("active");           
        $(".hot-state").addClass("hidden");
    }, 2000);
});

<div class="plus"></div>
<img class="reg-state active" src="images/SVG/circle.svg">
<img class="hot-state hidden" src="images/SVG/circlered.svg">
```

Comment: @RyanWilson see when you are clicking the div, it is adding a color state to the image. And I need that color state to stay before it reverses back to its idle state for a few seconds after clicking is over.

Comment: ah, ok. Now things make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new timeout for each click.  If you want it to happen only after the click has stopped, you can try the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var throttle = null;
  
  $(".plus").click(function() {
    if (throttle) clearTimeout(throttle);
    
    $(".reg-state").removeClass("active");
    $(".reg-state").addClass("hidden");
    $(".hot-state").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".hot-state").addClass("active");

    throttle = setTimeout(function() {
      throttle = null;
      
      $(".reg-state").removeClass("hidden");
      $(".reg-state").addClass("active");
      $(".hot-state").removeClass("active");
      $(".hot-state").addClass("hidden");
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

This will destroy the timeout every time the user clicks the element, provided it's within 2 seconds, the time of your timeout.