# Optimize jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic search function that sorts through a list of names. There are about 4,000 names so this loop is a bit to slow to keep up as users type. Here is the loop for each new search value:

```
elements.each(function(i, el){
    var name = $(el).find('button').text();
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    if(name.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $(el).show().addClass('visible');
    }
    else {
        $(el).hide().removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

How can I optimize this loop so it can keep up with a user typing?

Follow up:
Based on user suggestions, I mapped and stored the data in an array when the text input receives focus. Then, I changed the active search to the below:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.cache, function(el, i){
    var name = el.name;
    if(name.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        el.element.style.display = '';
        el.element.classList.add('visible');
    }
    else {
        el.element.style.display = 'none';
        el.element.classList.remove('visible');
    }
});
```

I tried to cut off jQuery where I could to better optimize. It seems to be working without any noticeable lag now! Thanks for the great suggestions and discussion.

Comment: Throttle the event so you only loop after the user stops typing for a given amount of time.  Say 350 milliseconds.  Other than that, `$(el)` is repeated three times in the logic.  That's three repetative jQuery object creations (technically two since two are in an if/else, but ya know).

Comment: If your buttons are static, pre-process the data and keep it in a HashMap (dictionary) and get smarter about what you display (for instance most of the `.removeClass('visible')` operations are redundant. Also throttle down as @Taplar mentioned

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076520/execute-my-settimeout-function-after-clicking-stops/49076561#49076561  This version was for clicking, but it can be changed for typing.

Comment: Use a `delayed debounce` script on your keyup event handler.  on keypress, set timeout on next keypress clear timeout and set it again, etc.

Comment: When you call `.show` / `.hide` it starts that action immediately - instead, you could run your elements.each with add/remove class and then `$(".visible").show()` `$(":not(.visible)").hide()` to show/hide them all in one go (add another class to find them more easily, eg `var rows = $(".row"); rows.fitler(".visible").show(); rows.filter(":not(.visible)").hide();`)

Comment: Small side note, not intended to derail, but what's up with doing a show().addClass('visible') and hide().removeClass('visible')?  Kinda feels redundant

Comment: @freedomn-m well, native for jQuery which is used by OP. The point is that it is ready to use and there is nothing to invent

Comment: Another option: use `.map` to filter them and then apply the class/hide/show as appropriate.

Comment: Why `map` over `filter`?

Comment: And filter on only the items you have left

Comment: @freedomn-m my fault, didn't use jQuery since two years... Thought it became better :D Stupid me

Comment: @Taplar no reason, I tend to forget that you can use `filter` with a callback, so I use `.map` with callbacks and `.filter` with selectors

Comment: Gotcha, just thought it was odd since the ability exists there and you're trying to filter things, not transform them, :)

Comment: In this case `.map` would add extra overhead, especially with 4,000 rows.

Comment: Don't touch the dom in your loop. If that means creating an array of data to filter through beforehand, it'd still be better than touching the dom 4k*n times for each keystroke.

Comment: In reply to the comment about the visible class, this is used by another action and doesn't actually affect visibility.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

jQuery is sloooooooooooooooow, if you can do your looping and most of your heavily repeated functionality in vanilla JS, you will save a lot of processing time. Also pre-mapping text is huge, looking up the button element and getting the text value every time is a big waste.

```js
/*
elements.each(function(i, el){
    var name = $(el).find('button').text();
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    if(name.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $(el).show().addClass('visible');
    }
    else {
        $(el).hide().removeClass('visible');
    }
});
*/

let elemQueryArr = elements.map(elem => {
  return {
    elem: elem,
    text: elem.querySelector('button').text.toLowerCase()
  }
}), len = elemQueryArr.length
  
function filterElems(val){
  let i = -1
  while(++i < len){
    let elem = elemQueryArr[i]
    if(elem.text.indexOf(val) > -1) elem.elem.classList.add('visible')
    else elem.elem.classList.remove('visible')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @Taplar, you could delay the error-check.

Not everything has to be real-time, as it could harm the usability.

It's common to check something in a timespan after the the system stops receiving the action, and while user is typing, you could just grey out the status text and once 500ms after user stops typing passes, you execute the check and assign necessary class to the status text.

Here's an example implementation. It won't throw a "error" unless you type "BAD" in the text box.

```js
var timeout;
$("#txt").keydown(function(e){
  $("#status").removeClass("bad").addClass("wait");
  clearInterval(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(checkStuff, 500);
});

function checkStuff(){
  var t = $("#txt").val();
  var s = $("#status");
  s.removeClass("wait").html("No errors");
  if(t.indexOf("BAD") > -1) {
    s.addClass("bad").html("Errors detected!");
  }
}
```

```css
#status{
  color:green;
}
#status.wait{
  color:rgba(150,150,150,1);
}
#status.bad{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" placeholder="type plz"><br>
<span id="status">No errors</span>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really apply to the question. I already have the keystrokes handled in a manner that was given to me. I just need to speed up this particular action. Thanks, though!